# How to window leftcol without switching to the window

Tags: vim-windows, scrolling

`winsaveview()` returns multiple details about the window including the `leftcol` which is the amount of horizontal scroll. However you need to switch to the window to get that. `getwininfo()` returns almost all information, for instance `topline` to determine the vertical scroll except the horizontal scroll. I'm just wondering if there is a way to horizontal scroll without window switching.

Comment: Isn't this the `wincol` attribute on `getwininfo()`?

Comment: Actually, maybe not; it says it's related to `win_screenpos()`. The two clauses there seem contradictory :(

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Nope. That is the position of the window from the left.